# is there a way I can I use regex to list end-notes in numerical order

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-code

So I am new to html. I have a word document that has over 300 footnotes/endnotes. However when I am encoding the document using html the endotes lose their order and starts to repeat themselves. I am using VS Code. Example:

---

**Word doc**

This is the first sentence and this is the source. [1] This is the second sentence and this is the source [2] This is the third sentence. [3] This is the fourth sentence.[4] And this is the final sentence.[5]

---

**HTML doc**

This is the first sentence and this is the source. **[1]** This is the second sentence and this is the source **[2]** This is the third sentence. **[1]** This is the fourth sentence.**[2]** And this is the final sentence.**[2]**

---

I am using the regex `<sup>.*?</sup>` to **find** the endnotes in the HTML doc. However I can't come up with a method or regex that would **replace** the endnotes with ones that are in numerical order. IF that is even possible. I have seen other examples use `<sup>$1</sup>` as the regex to step through each endnote in the HTML and **replace** in numerical order. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with an extension, like [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) (which I authored).

In your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(<sup>)\\d(</sup>)",
    "replace": "$1${matchNumber}$2",
    "isRegex": true
  }
}
```

`(<sup>)\\d(</sup>)` your `find` query, must double-escape the `\d`

Replace with  `$1${matchNumber}$2` which is capture group 1 followed by the number of the match (the first match, second match, etc. in the document), followed by the second capture group.

[image: replace with match number]

Comment: Thanks for this. However when I input in (<sup>)\\d(</sup>) in Find, no results come unless I remove the escape and make in "\d".

Comment: You have to use the keybinding, not the Find widget.  For the keybinding you need the `\\d`, not in the Find widget.  The Find widget does not support replacing with the match number.

Comment: Ok, I did it over and it works now. Thanks a million!